# Add item to Linq to SQL IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, generics, dynamic

I'm trying to add an item to an IQueryable result.

I currently do it as follows:

```
 var company_none = new[] {
                         new {
                            company_id = (int?)null,
                            descr = "<NONE>"
                         }};


            var company_result = (from c in companies
                               select new
                               {
                                   c.company_id,
                                   c.descr
                               });

 var result = company_none.Concat(company_result)
```

I want to create a method that will accept a type and create the "company_none" dynamically based on the type passed to it. Of course the type will determine what properties the anonymous type will contain. I've tried ExpandoObject with a dictionary but it will not recognize the null. It simply removes it if a property is null. So in short how do I create an anonymous type object like the"company_none" dynamically at runtime?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried generics?

Comment: Generics isn't the problem its creating the new object. I can get the type, get its properties but then how do I create the anonymous type dynamically without using ExpandoObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        var constructor_parameters = typeof(T).GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();

        if (parameters.Count != constructor_parameters.Length) throw new ArgumentException("Passed parameters count differs from real property count.");
        if (constructor_parameters.Any(p => !parameters.ContainsKey(p))) throw new ArgumentException("Some of properties are not present in a dictionary.");

        var newobject = new T[] { (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), constructor_parameters.Select(name=>parameters[name]).ToArray()) };
        return input.Concat(newobject);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = new string[]{ "5", "6" }.Select(i => new { a = 2, b = i });
var newprops = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "a", 8 }, { "b", "test" } };

var res = data.Append(newprops).ToArray();
```

Comment: @user3478586 Let me know if you're having troubles with this snippet

Comment: That appears to work except it converts my (int?)null to 0, but that's something I'm sure I can figure out how to fix. Did you just come with that on the fly? If so, very impressive. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...I guess it does work after all. The field is non nullable and appears to be the reason I couldn't make it null. It defaulted it to 0. Changing the field to nullable made (int?)null work just fine.